# How to handle lock on a db entity in a multithreaded application?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following two methods:

```
public void retrieveAndInsert(String number){
     Entity e = repository.findByNumber(number).orElseGet(() -> new Entity());
     //...update some part of the entity... 
     repository.save(e);
}
public void deleteEntity(String number){
  repository.deleteByNumber(number);
}
```

Those two methods can be called from batches and I'm afraid of the following sequence:

- Retrieve is called by a thread and retrieves the entity, starting the update
- Meanwhile the delete is called and the underlying row is deleted
- What happens when save() is called on the first method? Theoretically the entity will be detached from the database while still preserving the ID

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: What database are you using? It may depend on your isolation level.

Comment: microsoft sql server